# onChange to calculate total for multiple rows doesn't work

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am trying to calculate the total price for each new item added. I have created an onchange function that will calculate the total price based on the quantity inputted by the user, so every time the user changes the quantity, the price changes. I have tried running my code however it doesn't seem to be calculating and displaying the total in its corresponding text box.

**JavaScript**

```
function getTotal($i)
{
var price = document.getElementById('priceper_'+$i+'').value;
var per_pack = document.getElementById('per_pack_'+$i+'').value;
var quantity = document.getElementById('quantity_'+$i+'').value;

document.getElementById('subtotal_'+$i+'').value = ((price/per_pack)*quantity);
}
```

**HTML/PHP:**

```
<table>
<tr>
<td>Paper</td>
<td align="center">Price</td>
<td align="center">Per Pack</td>
<td align="center">Quantity</td>
<td align="center">Sub Total</td>
</tr>
<tr class="multipp">
<td><input type="text" name="description_0" id="description_" size="85" maxlength="70" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($description[0]); ?>" /></td>
<td><input type="text" name="priceper_0" id="priceper_" size="10" maxlength="9" value="" /></td>
<td><input type="text" name="per_pack_0" id="per_pack_" size="10" maxlength="9" value="" /></td>
<td><input type="text" name="quantity_0" id="quantity_" size="10" maxlength="9" onChange="getTotal($i);"/></td>
<td><input type="text" name="subtotal_0" id="subtotal_" size="15" maxlength="9" value="" /></td>
</tr>
<?php
for($i=1; $i<10; $i++)
{
  echo '<tr class="multipp">';
  echo '<td><input type="text" name="description_'.$i.'" id="description_'.$i.'" size="85" maxlength="70" value="'.htmlspecialchars($description[$i]).'" /></td>';
  echo '<td><input type="text" name="priceper_'.$i.'" id="priceper_'.$i.'" size="10" maxlength="9" value="'.htmlspecialchars($priceper[$i]).'" /></td>';
  echo '<td><input type="text" name="per_pack_'.$i.'" id="per_pack_'.$i.'" class="txt" size="10" maxlength="9" value="'.htmlspecialchars($priceper[$i]).'" /></td>';
  echo '<td><input type="text" name="quantity_'.$i.'" id="quantity_'.$i.'" size="10" maxlength="9" onChange="getTotal($i);" value="'.htmlspecialchars($quantity[$i]).'" /></td>';
  echo '<td><input type="text" name="subtotal_'.$i.'" id="subtotal_'.$i.'" size="15" maxlength="9" value="'.htmlspecialchars($subtotal[$i]).'" /></td>';
  echo '</tr>';
}
?>
</table>
```

Comment: Please create a jsfiddle for us to be able to test your script. Have you checked for javascript errors ?

Comment: You can't use php variables interchangeably with JavaScript like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this :

```
 echo '<td><input type="text" name="quantity_'.$i.'" id="quantity_'.$i.'" size="10" maxlength="9" onChange="getTotal($i);" value="'.htmlspecialchars($quantity[$i]).'" /></td>';
```

to

```
 echo '<td><input type="text" name="quantity_'.$i.'" id="quantity_'.$i.'" size="10" maxlength="9" onChange="getTotal('.$i.');" value="'.htmlspecialchars($quantity[$i]).'" /></td>';
```

Here, `onChange="getTotal($i);"` $i is not interpreted since you are making a string surrounded by simple quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Your below code line:

```
<input type="text" name="quantity_0" id="quantity_" size="10" maxlength="9" onChange="getTotal($i);"/></td>
```

should be this

```
<input type="text" name="quantity_0" id="quantity_0" size="10" maxlength="9" onChange="getTotal(<?php echo $i;?>);"/></td>
```

And the below code line:

```
echo '<td><input type="text" name="quantity_'.$i.'" id="quantity_'.$i.'" size="10" maxlength="9" onChange="getTotal($i);" value="'.htmlspecialchars($quantity[$i]).'" /></td>'
```

Should be this:

```
echo '<td><input type="text" name="quantity_'.$i.'" id="quantity_'.$i.'" size="10" maxlength="9" onChange="getTotal('.$i.');" value="'.htmlspecialchars($quantity[$i]).'" />`</td>'
```

And in javascript code replace the `$i` with the `i` as $i is the format of php.